# ANR in removeMessages and enqueueMessage

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-anr-dialog

I have the following ANR after entering and exiting (several times) a screen which uses an AsyncTask to load some data.

The full ANR is here: http://pastebin.com/g1MDv44Q

A few observations:

- My package name doesn't appear anywhere on the stacks
- The "main" thread is SUSPENDED
- There are a lot of threads in WAIT, this number increases each time and enter/exit the screen

I also noticed that the two SUSPENDED threads seem to be in some sort of deadlock or infinite loop, one "removing messages" and the other "enqueueing messages":

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x415dce88 self=0x414fb898
  | sysTid=9246 nice=-6 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074143572
  | state=S schedstat=( 487768247094 88677560041 387007 ) utm=45537 stm=3239 core=3
  at android.os.MessageQueue.removeMessages(MessageQueue.java:~472)
  at android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks(Handler.java:479)
  at android.view.View.removeCallbacks(View.java:11343)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.stop(RecyclerView.java:3914)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.stopScrollersInternal(RecyclerView.java:1641)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setScrollState(RecyclerView.java:1112)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.cancelTouch(RecyclerView.java:2252)
  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2237)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7837)
  ...

"Thread-28544" prio=4 tid=99 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x451703d0 self=0x7bc9d658
  | sysTid=13075 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-2111467576
  | state=S schedstat=( 4705817143 4247615417 4666 ) utm=444 stm=26 core=3
  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:~359)
  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:626)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:595)
  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:566)
  at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(Handler.java:530)
  at android.os.Handler.sendEmptyMessage(Handler.java:515)
  at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.setTimer(SystemMessageHandler.java:30)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Is this analysis correct?

**If yes**, why is it happening and how can I fix or prevent it?

**If not**, what is the correct analysis for this [ANR](http://pastebin.com/g1MDv44Q)?

Comment: any chances that every RecyclerView's item has a webview? ... and you had a lots of the items? and loading the url in bindViewHolder?

Comment: no, there aren't any webviews!

Comment: actually it seems it is the AdView from AdMob, it probably uses some kind of WebView on it!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue in the M33 milestone of chromium (M33 impacts Android 4.4.3 and 4.4.4), where every timer event is removing the handler messages and re-scheduling a new timer message very rapidly.  The issue was [fixed](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/17ee1ffb8d1fcc7df3ea97f8bc571c4d53477c90) after M33, but unfortunately KitKat does not support updating Chromium from Google Play Store, so that fix cannot be applied without updating to Lollipop (5.0) or later.  The suspect line is:

`at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.setTimer(SystemMessageHandler.java:30)`